# Zend Framework: route cyrillic url to static file

Tags: .htaccess, zend-framework

That is my url:

> http://site.com/presentations/тест-тест.ppt

Presentations is folder in public folder, but when I open this link are appear this error:

> Invalid controller specified (presentations)

That is my .htaccess file:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV production


RewriteEngine On
#RewriteBase all4you/public/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|swf|html|pps)$ index.php [NC,L]


order allow,deny
allow from all
```

That is my google iframe:

```
<iframe class="school-ppt-material-cont" src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=<?= $fileSrc ?>&embedded=true" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

That is `$fileSrc`, but if presentation name is cyrillic google viewer can't open file, but if file name is no-cyrillic(exp. 'test') google viewer can open file:

```
$fileSrc = 'http://mysite/presentations/тест-тест.ppt';
$fileSrc = 'http://mysite/presentations/test-test.ppt';
```

Comment: what is the filename on your disk/server? cyrillic or latin?

Answer (score 0):

Are you configure mod_rewrite in the right way? Files should not be redirected to the index.php. My example of `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Adapt your last rule to

```
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|swf|html|pps|ppt)$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: If URL is http://site.com/presentations/тест-тест.ppt don't open file but if URL is http://site.com/presentations/test-test.ppt file is open

Comment: the cyrillic file-names/urls are a different problem I think

Comment: please update your question and add information on which file you want to retrieve with which url